# Change to show in Label only "The date is 15 January 2015 08:15) with out the seconds and +0000

Tags: ios, objective-c

> **// //  ViewController.h //  Date // //  Created by Daniel Habshush on 30.04.15. //  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
>   //**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {UIDatePicker *datepick;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
}

-(IBAction)button;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepick;

@end
```

> **// //  ViewController.m //  Date // //  Created by Daniel Habshush on 30.04.15. //  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
>   //**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface UIViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize datepick;

-(IBAction)button {
    NSDate *choise=[datepick date];
    NSString *words = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The PickUp date is %@", choise];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"The Title" message:words delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    label.text=words;
    textfield.text = words;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the NSDateFormatter class with -setDateFormat: and -stringFromeDate:. Here's a link to the apple documentation [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). It'll point you to the Unicode Technical Standards that are used for most code. For a more specific answer you'll want to do this:

```
NSDate *choise=[datepick date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm"];
NSString *words = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The PickUp date is %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:choise]];
```

Comment: If you are going to use the 12-hour format for the hour, you should add the `a` specifier for AM/PM.

Comment: good point, if you want 12-hour format then the format should be
    @"dd MMMM yyyy hh:mma"
for 24-hour format you'll want
    @"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *choise = [datepick date];
NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm"];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The date is %@", [dFormatter stringFromDate:d]];
```

Comment: If you are going to use the 12-hour format for the hour, you should add the `a` specifier for AM/PM.